# Poetry add same library for different Python versions

Tags: python, python-packaging, python-poetry, pyproject.toml

I know how to add python constraint for a single library

```ini
flake8 = { version = "^6.0.0", python = ">=3.8.1" }
```

But what if I want to have same library, but different version for a different Python version? In case I add it with another constraint it produces an error

```
Invalid TOML file /home/user/mylib/pyproject.toml: Key "flake8" already exists.
```

For example, I want my package to support Python `^3.7` but latest `flake8` is only compatible with `>=3.8.1`. How to I add `flake8` specification which will be installed for `python = "<3.8.1"`.

Is it possible to achieve at all? Should I create another release calleb `mylib-3.7` just to support earlier Python versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [multiple constraints dependencies](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#multiple-constraints-dependencies):

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
flake8 = [
    {version = "^5.0", python = ">=3.6,<3.8"},
    {version = "^6.0", python = ">=3.8"}
]
```